# Residually finite group surjective to nonresidually finite group with finitely generated kernel

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

As is described in the title, is there a known example such that there is a surjective homomorphism of groups $$f: G\rightarrow H,$$ with $G$ and $H$ finitely presented, $G$ is residually finite, and $H$ is non-residually finite, such that $\ker f$ is finitely generated?

Comment: There are very concrete examples of matrix groups $G$ with this property. See for example the paper: Yves de Cornulier, *Finitely presentable, non-Hopfian groups with Kazhdan’s property (T) and infinite outer automorphism group*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 135 (2007), no. 4, 951-959.

Comment: (1) Abels constructed in 1978 a finitely presented, residually finite (linear), solvable group $G$ with a cyclic central subgroup $Z$ such that $G/Z$ is not residually finite. (2) The paper of mine quoted by Andreas is a similar construction, with "solvable" replaced with "with Kazhdan's Property T". (3) Ben's answer gives examples answering the question with $G$ hyperbolic (in which case we can't expect the kernel to be cyclic or central).

Comment: @AndreasThom  Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @YCor  Thank you so much for your explanation!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can obtain such a surjection for any finitely presented non-residually finite group $H$ using Daniel Wise's residually finite Rips construction, which is the main result of this paper: [A Residually Finite Version of Rips's Construction.](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024609302001406)